# How to solve $\int_0^{2}\frac{x\log(2-x)}{1+x^2} \; dx $

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I have problem to find the value of the integral:

$$ \int_0^{2}\frac{x\log(2-x)}{1+x^2} \; dx $$

The first step is to split the absolute part.
I thank you in advance for help.

Comment: This integral diverges.

Comment: Really the exercise tells to study the integral-function from 0 to x. As the consequence if the integral diverges to +/- infty,  I suppose that we have a limited bound in which it exists. What do you think about?

Comment: @xpaul : does the $ \int_0^{-2} f(x) dx $ diverge for you?

Comment: It is easy to check that it converges.

Comment: @xpaul: I see (and prove) it converges. The problem for me is to solve it using the polylogaritthmic functions...

Comment: edit your question first.

Comment: @xpaul:I try to open e question with the exact integral so we can discover if we can found the solution with polylog functions.Thank you very much.

Comment: you don't need to open. Just edit your question.

Comment: that's it : I need to evaluate this integral $ \int_0^2(x(log(2-x)))\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx $

Comment: I changed for you.

Comment: Thank you  for help to adjust the question.I hope that someone reach to solve it or to find a good (& simple :-)) solution.

Answer (score 4):

---

Let $\mathcal{I}$ denote the value of the following definite integral:

$$\mathcal{I}:=\int_{0}^{2}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{x\ln{\left(2-x\right)}}{1+x^{2}}\approx-0.323799.$$

---

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}
&=\int_{0}^{2}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{x\ln{\left(2-x\right)}}{1+x^{2}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to2^{-}}\left[\frac12\ln{\left(2-x\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{1+x^{2}}{5}\right)}\right]-\lim_{x\to0}\left[\frac12\ln{\left(2-x\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{1+x^{2}}{5}\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~-\int_{0}^{2}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{(-1)\ln{\left(\frac{1+x^{2}}{5}\right)}}{2\left(2-x\right)};~~~\small{I.B.P.}\\
&=\frac12\ln{\left(2\right)}\ln{\left(5\right)}+\int_{0}^{2}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{1+x^{2}}{5}\right)}}{2\left(2-x\right)}\\
&=\frac12\ln{\left(2\right)}\ln{\left(5\right)}+\int_{0}^{2}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{1+(2-y)^{2}}{5}\right)}}{2y};~~~\small{\left[x=2-y\right]}\\
&=\frac12\ln{\left(2\right)}\ln{\left(5\right)}+\int_{0}^{2}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{5-4y+y^{2}}{5}\right)}}{2y}\\
&=\frac12\ln{\left(2\right)}\ln{\left(5\right)}+\int_{0}^{\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\sqrt{5}\ln{\left(\frac{5-4\sqrt{5}\,t+5t^{2}}{5}\right)}}{2\sqrt{5}\,t};~~~\small{\left[y=\sqrt{5}\,t\right]}\\
&=\frac12\ln{\left(2\right)}\ln{\left(5\right)}+\int_{0}^{\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln{\left(1-\frac{4}{\sqrt{5}}\,t+t^{2}\right)}}{2t}.\\
\end{align}$$

---

**Digression Proving an Integral Formula.**

Define the function $f:(0,\pi)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ via the definite integral

$$f{\left(\theta\right)}:=-\int_{0}^{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln{\left(1-2x\cos{\left(\theta\right)}+x^{2}\right)}}{2x}.$$

Note that $f{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}=0$.

It is possible to derive a closed-form expression for $f$ in terms of the dilogarithm (and elementary functions): for any $\theta\in(0,\pi)$,

$$\begin{align}
f{\left(\theta\right)}
&=f{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}+\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\theta}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,f^{\prime}{\left(\varphi\right)};~~~\small{F.T.C.}\\
&=0+\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\theta}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{d}{d\varphi}\left[-\int_{0}^{\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln{\left(1-2x\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}+x^{2}\right)}}{2x}\right]\\
&=\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\theta}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{d}{d\varphi}\int_{0}^{\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}}\mathrm{d}x\,\left[-\frac{\ln{\left(1-2x\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}+x^{2}\right)}}{2x}\right]\\
&=\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\theta}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{d}{d\varphi}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\left[-\frac{\ln{\left(1-2y\cos^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}+y^{2}\cos^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}\right)}}{2y}\right];~~~\small{\left[x=y\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}\right]}\\
&=\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\theta}\mathrm{d}\varphi\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\partial}{\partial\varphi}\left[-\frac{\ln{\left(1-2y\cos^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}+y^{2}\cos^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}\right)}}{2y}\right]\\
&=\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\theta}\mathrm{d}\varphi\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\left(y-2\right)\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}\sin{\left(\varphi\right)}}{1-2y\cos^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}+y^{2}\cos^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}}\\
&=\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\theta}\mathrm{d}\varphi\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\left(y-2\right)\tan{\left(\varphi\right)}}{\sec^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}-2y+y^{2}}\\
&=-\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\theta}\mathrm{d}\varphi\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\left(2-y\right)\tan{\left(\varphi\right)}}{\left(1-y\right)^{2}+\tan^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}}\\
&=-\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\theta}\mathrm{d}\varphi\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\left(1+t\right)\tan{\left(\varphi\right)}}{t^{2}+\tan^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}};~~~\small{\left[y=1-t\right]}\\
&=-\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\theta}\mathrm{d}\varphi\int_{0}^{\cot{\left(\varphi\right)}}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{1+u\tan{\left(\varphi\right)}}{1+u^{2}};~~~\small{\left[t=u\tan{\left(\varphi\right)}\right]}\\
&=-\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\theta}\mathrm{d}\varphi\int_{0}^{\cot{\left(\varphi\right)}}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{d}{du}\left[\arctan{\left(u\right)}+\frac12\tan{\left(\varphi\right)}\ln{\left(1+u^{2}\right)}\right]\\
&=-\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\theta}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\left[\arctan{\left(\cot{\left(\varphi\right)}\right)}+\frac12\tan{\left(\varphi\right)}\ln{\left(1+\cot^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}\right)}\right]\\
&=-\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\theta}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\left[\frac{\pi}{2}-\varphi+\frac12\tan{\left(\varphi\right)}\ln{\left(\csc^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}\right)}\right]\\
&=-\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\theta}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\varphi\right)-\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\theta}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac12\tan{\left(\varphi\right)}\ln{\left(\csc^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}\right)}\\
&=\frac12\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)^{2}-\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\theta}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{(-1)\sin{\left(\varphi\right)}}{2\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}}\ln{\left(1-\cos^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}\right)}\\
&=\frac12\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)^{2}-\int_{0}^{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{2x}\ln{\left(1-x^{2}\right)};~~~\small{\left[\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}=x\right]}\\
&=\frac12\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)^{2}-\frac14\int_{0}^{\cos^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1-y\right)}}{y};~~~\small{\left[x^{2}=y\right]}\\
&=\frac12\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)^{2}+\frac14\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\cos^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

---

Returning to the evaluation of $\mathcal{I}$, set $\theta:=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arcsin{\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\right)}$. Then, $\cos{\left(\theta\right)}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$, and we obtain the following final result:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}
&=\frac12\ln{\left(2\right)}\ln{\left(5\right)}+\int_{0}^{\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln{\left(1-\frac{4}{\sqrt{5}}\,t+t^{2}\right)}}{2t}\\
&=\frac12\ln{\left(2\right)}\ln{\left(5\right)}+\int_{0}^{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln{\left(1-2t\cos{\left(\theta\right)}+t^{2}\right)}}{2t}\\
&=\frac12\ln{\left(2\right)}\ln{\left(5\right)}-f{\left(\theta\right)}\\
&=\frac12\ln{\left(2\right)}\ln{\left(5\right)}-\frac12\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)^{2}-\frac14\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\cos^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}\right)}\\
&=\frac12\ln{\left(2\right)}\ln{\left(5\right)}-\frac12\arcsin^{2}{\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\right)}-\frac14\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac45\right)}.\blacksquare\\
\end{align}$$

---

Comment: Thank you David for your precious answer.I compared your solution with other and it seems to be the same.Now I am finding a simbolic solution to $ {Li}_{2}{(\frac45})$ I think that the only way is "numeric" for this kind of $ Li_2 $ argument (4/5).

Comment: in your solution we have $\frac12\arcsin^{2}$ term and $\frac14{Li}_{2}{(\frac45)}$. On the other we have only $ {Li}_{2}{(\frac45)}$. So if we cansidering them with minus sign it seems to be the same. What do you think about?

Answer (score 3):

Using
\begin{eqnarray} 
&&\int \frac{\log(b-x)}{x+a}\;dx\\
&=&\int \log(b-x)d\log\frac{x+a}{a+b}\;dx\\
&=&\log(b-x)\log\frac{x+a}{a+b}-\int \frac1{b-x}\log\frac{x+a}{a+b}\;dx\\
&=&\log(b-x)\log\frac{x+a}{a+b}-\int \frac1{b-x}\log\bigg(1-\frac{b-x}{a+b}\bigg)\;dx\\
&=&\log(b-x)\log\frac{x+a}{a+b}+\text{Li}_2(\frac{b-x}{a+b})+C
\end{eqnarray}
one has
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_0^{2}\frac{x\log(2-x)}{1+x^2} \; dx\\
&=&\frac12\int_0^2\log(2-x)\bigg(\frac1{x+i}+\frac1{x-i}\bigg)\,dx\\
&=&\frac12\log2\log5-\frac12\bigg[\text{Li}_2\bigg(\frac{4}{5}-\frac{2i}{5}\bigg)+\text{Li}_2\bigg(\frac{4}{5}+\frac{2i}{5}\bigg)\bigg]
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: @Thank you very much. As a consequence the immaginary unit desappear on the final solution. Does  the $1/2i $ left-factor depends on the hermite-formula applied to $ \frac{x}{1+x^2}$? Thank you again for your precious

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: I see around the web the evaluation of $
\text{Li}_2(2,\frac{b-x}{a+b})$ without success. I try to find it also into on old answer here, without success. Could you suggest me something?

Comment: ...or likewise $ \text{Li}_2(\frac{x+i}{i+2}) $ and  $ \text{Li}_2(\frac{x-i}{2-i}) $. Considering that it can appear as a new question grow-up (I don't see here), I can put as new post. Let me know.

Comment: @xpaul I'm pretty sure $\text{Li}_2(\color{red}{2,}\frac{b-x}{a+b})$ is a typo and should just be $\text{Li}_2(\frac{b-x}{a+b})$, correct?

Comment: @DavidH Yes, you're right.

Comment: @xpaul: thank you very very much!The final term is only a real number 
(taking into account the Li2(z) dilogarithmic function series expression).
So we have $\text{Li}_2(z)+\text{Li}_2(\bar{z})=\sum_{1}^{+\infty}(a)^n/n^2 $, where $a=\frac{4}{5}$
Correct me if I write above something wrong.

Comment: @Alex, you're right.

Comment: @xpaul , so we find a simple method to calculate the integral above between various intervals...very very good and thank you for your big patience!!!!Thanks again...